# Decomposing MP3s in Java

Tags: java, audio, mp3

What is the most popular method/API for reading in an MP3 and turning it into its most basic amplitude waveform (a float that could represent a point on a waveform for visualisation) and then how can I use this basic value to play it out on the computer's audio output? (All of this done in Java)

Comment: (all of this done in Java), so in other words you are asking us to write you a full application?

Comment: No of course I'm not. I'd like pointers to what API I should be using (or collection of APIs) and perhaps a tutorial document if there is such a thing out there.

Comment: Well you can always spend the $220 and buy the spec, then work it out from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [LAMEOnJ](http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj/). It is a Java wrapper for LAME ([JavaDoc](http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj/javadoc/index.html)).

As for converting byte arrays to float arrays, how about importing `java.nio.ByteBuffer` and `java.nio.ByteOrder`, and doing the following

```
float floatVal = ByteBuffer.wrap(array).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).getFloat();
```

That should do the trick to give you a float array. As for playing it, you could just assign each float value a pitch.

Comment: That may work for an uncompressed format, but for MP3s you have to read data frames and uncompress them, which is no trivial task.

Comment: Just a few things: it's not an *implementation*, it's a *wrapper* for the standard LAME (native) library; second, it uses a commercial, closed source product (for no sensible reason that I can understand). It would probably be much better to just do a simpler wrapper (of a simpler library, maybe) from the scratch.

Comment: Lots of things would be better if they were custom-coded! :P

I based my answer off of the fact that ExtremeCoder is asking for an API?

Comment: I would have downvoted if I had a better answer to give; as it is, I just wanted to point out some of the drawbacks of yours.

Comment: Huh - it said "0 down vote" in the first part of my last response... Weird - some kind of bug? Anyway, you made good suggestions as to the drawbacks. Thanks! :)

Comment: The small pencil icon shows that the comment has been edited.